# Why is $E(X_2|X_1) = X_1$?

Tags: statistics

From textbook: $f(x_1, x_2) = 2 e^{-x_2/x_1},$ where $ 0 <  x_1 < 1$, and $ x_2 > 0.$ The marginal is $f(x_1) = 2x_1$, and accordingly $$f(x_2|x_1) = \frac{1}{x_1}e^{-x_2/x_1}.$$

My calculation $$E(X_2|X_1) = \int^{\infty}_{0} x_2 \frac{1}{x_1}e^{-x_2/x_1} = x_1.$$

Since the conditional is not given with $X_1 = x_1$, why does textbook say that $$E(X_2|X_1) = X_1$$

Comment: You are actually computing $E(X_2\mid X_1=x_1)$ as being $x_1$ for every $x_1$ in $(0,1)$, hence indeed $E(X_2\mid X_1)=X_1$ almost surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional expectation is

$$E(X_2\mid X_1) = f(X_1)$$

where $f(x) = E(X_2 \mid X_1 = x)$. You found that $f(x) = x$, hence

$$E(X_2 \mid X_1) = f(X_1)  = X_1$$